# How to write and read the period of the first years of the century

Tags: reading-aloud

*This musical style emerged in the mid-'00s of this century.*

Is it possible to write the period between 2005–2010 in this form? And how to read it? "Null(t)ies"? "Zerothies"?

Comment: I say "oh-ohs".

Comment: I say the "mid-naughts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BBC recommended broadcasting style of wording for this period](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/stories/noughties/) would be *"the mid-noughties"*.

This is because it contains a nice pun which the British find amusing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no consensus on what to call the first ten years of a century, despite the fact that we've already finished them. What I've hear most is just "The two-thousands," to refer the first 10 years of this century. There's an [entire article written about this uncertainty on Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2009/12/the_uhohs.html).

[The question has also come up on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/997/what-is-the-name-of-the-first-decade-in-a-century).

In practical terms, "The two-thousands" isn't all that well liked because it's ambiguous. It could be referring to the first decade or the first century of the millennium.  So often, people will simply spell out what they are saying. How explicit you are depends on how much context you need to avoid ambiguity.

> "The/This past decade"
>
> "The/This last decade"
>
> "The first decade of the
> century"
>
> "From/Between 2000 and 2010"